# Lightning component is not passing the object to the controller as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

--Lightning app---

```
 <aura:application extends="force:slds" access="GLOBAL">
     <c:highcmp />
 </aura:application>
```

--Lightning Component---

```
  <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="HighController" access="global">
       <aura:attribute name="highValues" type="InnerClassInterface" default = "{'x':10,'y':15,'z':20}"/>
       <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.goHigh}"/>
  </aura:component>
```

-- JS Controller---

```
({
   goHigh : function(component, event, helper) {
      helper.sendHighValues(component, event);
   }
})
```

-- Helper---

```
({
sendHighValues : function(component, event) {

    var action = component.get("c.SampleMethod");

    var high = component.get("v.highValues");
    console.log('High = '+component.get("v.highValues"));

    action.setParams({

         "h1" : high

    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log("state: "+ state);
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){    
            console.log('Success');

        }else if (state === 'ERROR'){
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " +
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Something went wrong, Please check with your admin');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
   }

})
```

--Controller---

```
 public class HighController {    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void SampleMethod(High.Sample1 h1){
        system.debug('h1 value: '+ h1);
    }
 }
```

--Apex class--

```
public class High {
  public class Sample1 implements InnerClassInterface{
   @AuraEnabled
   public Integer x {public get; public set;}
   @AuraEnabled
   public Integer y {public get; public set;}
   @AuraEnabled
   public Integer z {public get; public set;}
  }
}
```

---Interface---

```
 public interface InnerClassInterface {

 }
```

In my Apex Controller, The debug statement is showing "null" for

system.debug('h1 value: '+ h1);   o/p: h1 value: null

I expected the o/p to be... o/p: h1 value: [x=10, y=15, z=20].

What changes Should I do to get the object ([x=10, y=15, z=20]) in the debug?

Comment: Change the type from innerclassinterface to map?

Comment: I am getting Internal Salesforce Error if I change the type from innerclassinterface to map

Comment: likely because your map is not properly set, please check [Collection Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm)

Comment: I couldn't fix it. Can you please tell me what needs to be changed?